# Minimum layout loading experience library in React

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, load

I want to know if React have some library for create a minimum layout for a website when is loading, something like Facebook does, e.g.:

[image: Minimum Layout Webapp]

I think that was called Sketch but not sure.

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://github.com/buildo/react-placeholder

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the "blurred" images/text.

Your best bet is probably to leverage the [`placeholder-loading`](https://github.com/zalog/placeholder-loading) library.

It uses CSS to accomplish this (so nothing React-specific).

[Here's an interesting blog post](https://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html) on how Facebook accomplishes it (and probably how `placeholder-loading` implements it).